# forkbomb automaticaly releases the resources?

Tags: command-line

I just ran the fork bomb command:

> :(){ :|: & };:

on my ubuntu machine and surprisingly, the system recovering automatically after few mins.  My observation is that, soon after running the fork bomb command on my ubuntu, I loose the shell access (some time only) and will be able to connect to the shell after few minutes of time. 
My understanding is that, the fork bomb consumes the complete system resources and doesn't release the resources automatically. Only way is to restart the system to get ride of the situation. In my case, it's not the case. 
**Can any body please help me to understand on why is the behavior (fork bomb hangs system only for few minutes)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux kernel was changed so that any user-process detected as grinding the system towards an eventual-halt (due to bug, or intentional with fork-bomb in this case) will be killed to preserve system stability. It works only until the kernel reaches its 'risk' threshold and thus kills it; a user-level bomb can't kill the system in modern linux

Comment: configuration can alter this (https://kerneltalks.com/scripts/bash-fork-bomb-how-it-works/) and it won't of course stop elevated-privilege jobs....

Comment: Do you know the kernel option enabling that functionality and on which kernel version this was introduced?

Comment: sorry nah, I can find references in various places but nothing authoritative (eg. "Nowadays, linux kernel support "memory. kmem.limit_in_bytes" cgroups settings to prevent fork bomb." [https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6479].   my comment & then answer were written from memory (things I've read) but I haven't found references [yet anyway]

Comment: (Kernel) changes made do not stop everything; but detect memory-resource-hogs like this common fork-bomb (if run with an ordinary account anyway).